# Handle dll not found exception

Tags: vb.net, dll, exception, import

My current project is working well, so like any sane person, I am trying to break it on purpose. One possibility is that some resources may go missing. When I neglect to put a dll in the run folder my application crashes spectacularly.

**Is it possible to "elegantly" handle exceptions that result from missing resources?**

One of my classes imports a resource that references "TcAdsDll.dll".   .

```
....
Imports Okuma.EthernetIO
....
```

In that class, I am able to catch the exception generated when I try to use this resource:

```
    Try
        Dim objAdsStateInfo As TwinCAT.Ads.StateInfo = Nothing
        Try
             'Do a bunch of fun stuff with Ethernet...
        Catch...  
        'catch Ethernet errors              
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
    'This catches the exception generated when I try to instantiate an object that uses the dll which is no longer present
    End Try
```

However, after I handle this exception, the program still proceeds to crash.
Once out of the initialization phase, form main is loaded and I get all the way to the end sub of that event. As soon as I execute the 'End Sub' statement (debugging line by line), I get the message:

```
DllNotFoundException was unhandled
Unable to load 'tcadsdll.dll': The specified module could not be found.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I've added code to check for the existence of this .dll before doing anything with the resource that uses it, but because it's linked into the class with an imports statement, it still tries to dispose it and crashes. Do I have to rebuild the resource (Okuma.EthernetIO) to include checking for the dll file? Or is there an elegant way to go about this easily in my application that I am just unaware of?

*UPDATE:* Checking for dll file existence before jumping into the class which contains the import is working for me. It stops the exception from being generated in the first place. However the question reamains:
**Is there any way to handle a dll not found exception?**

Comment: Very simple launcher app with minimal dependencies to check environment sanity before launch? Could display your splash screen as well.

Comment: ...or test for the existence of required files at startup and before you try to use them.  since you will or have written the installer, your app can know where to find them.

Comment: @Plutonix It is checking at startup (during initialization). One issue making it difficult is that I've got functionality split up into about 17 classes. My Initialization routine is called in the New() sub of form Main. That initialization calls an "InitEthernetIO()" in another class. That's where you see the code I posted above. It's this class that contains the imports statement for the offending resource, and not form main.

Answer (score 0):

You can "elegantly" handle a DLL not found exception by terminating the program:

```
Dim MissingDll as Boolean = False
Try
    'Do a bunch of fun stuff with Ethernet...
Catch ex As System.DllNotFoundException
    MissingDll = True
    MsgBox("Missing DLL", , "Fatal Error")
    Application.Exit()
End Try
```

In your shutdown code, use MissingDll to avoid calling other functions that would also cause "DllNotFoundException was unhandled" errors:

```
If Not MissingDll Then EthernetIO.Close()  ' something like this
```